# Distinct by property of List<class> inside a class

Tags: c#, linq

```
class Parent 
{ 
    string Name; 
    string Description; 
    List<Child> Actions;
}

class Child 
{
    string Action;
    string Value;
}
```

I have `List<parent> parents` and I want to retrieve the parent list with distinct `Value` property of the `Action` class.

I know I can use `parents.GroupBy(p => p.Actions).Select(f => f.First()).ToList()` but it doesn't work since `parent.Actions` is a list and I needed the distinct property value inside Actions, so `parent.Actions.Value`.

Input:

```
List<Parent> parents = 
parent1["name", "desc", Action["action", "uniqueAction1"]],
parent2["name", "desc", Action["action", "uniqueAction1"]], 
parent3["name", "desc", Action["action", "uniqueAction2"]]
```

Output:

```
List<Parent> parents = 
parent1["name", "desc", Action["action", "uniqueAction1"], 
parent3["name", "desc", Action["action", "uniqueAction2"]]
```

All of them should have unique properties of `parent.Actions.Value`.

Here's my solution without LINQ:

```
public List<Parent> FindUniqueParent()
{
  List<Parent> newParent = new List<Parent>();
  string previous = obj.Parents[0].Actions[0].Value; 
  newParent.Add(obj.Parents[0]);
  for (int i = 1; i < obj.Parents.Count; i++)
  {
      if (obj.Parents[i].Actions[0].Value != previous && !newParent.Contains(obj.Parents[i]))
      {
          newParent.Add(obj.Parents[i]);
          previous = obj.Parents[i].Actions[0].Value;
      }
      else
      {
          continue;
      }
  }
  return newParent;
}
```

obj is the Object that holds `List<Parent> parents` and parent holds `List<Child> child`.

If anyone else can improve the code or have a better solution, please let me know!

Comment: welcome - can you show your expected input/output?

Comment: I added the expected input and ouputs

Comment: If you switch the order of parent2 and parent3 in your input your code will result in 3 parents, is that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I totally get what you want but I imagine that you want to retrieve the List of strings of the "Value" inside every Action inside your list right? Well, you can retrieve the list as you said with the GroupBy method you mentioned and THEN you can create a new list and loop through the list to fill with the values you want, like this:

```
List<Child> parentList = parent.GroupBy(p => p.Actions).Select(f => f.First()).ToList();
List<string> valuesList = new List<string>();
foreach(Child child in parentList)
{
    valuesList.Add(child.Value);
}
```

And therefore your valuesList will be a list of all the values of your parent list

Comment: sorry please look at my edit for additional information regarding expected input and output.

Answer (score 0):

Your example code only looks at the first item in the `Parent.Actions` property so I'm going to assume that is what you want.  This should give you what you are after.

```
public List<Parent> FindUniqueParent()
{
    return obj.Parents.GroupBy(p => p.Actions[0].Value, (key, groups) => groups.FirstOrDefault())
           .ToList();
}
```

For your example data this gives:

[image]